# How to use google map API Client ID in desktop application

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have adobe flex application which serves html page which uses google map api. It's working with developer key.

I have a Maps API for Business license and want to use the Client ID of that license. But since it is not hosted, I don't have the option to add authorized URL.

Is there a way I can make this work?